# Outer loop terminating early

Tags: tex-core, loops

I'm trying to implement the Euclidean Algorithm in LaTeX.  Yes, I know I could do it more easily in python, but that's not the point.  I have an inner loop (extracted to a macro) to compute the remainder of one counter divided by another counter.  The outer loop should perform the inner loop, swap the values of the counters, and then repeat until one of the counters is 0.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\computeRemainder}[2]{%
  \loop
    \relax
  \ifnum \value{#1} > \value{#2}
    \addtocounter{#1}{-\value{#2}}
  \repeat
  \loop
    \relax
  \ifnum \value{#1} < 0
    \addtocounter{#1}{\value{#2}}
  \repeat}

\newcommand{\swapCounters}[2]{%
  \addtocounter{#1}{\value{#2}} % cA = A + B
  \addtocounter{#2}{\value{#1}} % cB = A + 2B
  \addtocounter{#1}{-\value{#2}} % cA = -B
  \setcounter{#2}{2*\value{#1}+\value{#2}} % cB = A
  \setcounter{#1}{-\value{#1}} % cA = B
}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{counterA}
\setcounter{counterA}{45}
\newcounter{counterB}
\setcounter{counterB}{27}

Before: \( A = \thecounterA, \; B = \thecounterB \) \\
\loop
  \computeRemainder{counterA}{counterB}
  \swapCounters{counterA}{counterB}
\ifnum \value{counterB} > 0
  Since this is true, shouldn't the loop continue? \\
\repeat
End: \( A = \thecounterA, \; B = \thecounterB \)

\end{document}
```

The above code produces the following output:

[image: Output of code]

My understanding of loops would suggest that, if it prints the text between `\ifnum \value{counterB} > 0` and `\repeat`, it should repeat the loop. 
 However, after this executes, both `counterA` and `counterB` are greater than 0.  Any idea why the outer loop won't continue?

Comment: you can't nest `\loop` at the same grouping level https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/tex-nested-loops

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed it, and it pointed out another bug I had.  (The first part of `\computeRemainder` should be >= instead of >, but I think LaTeX doesn't have >=, so I added an `\ifnum \value{#1} = \value{#2}` clause to subtract once more if needed.)

Comment: as it's integer arithmetic `if a >=b then x else y` is same as `if a<b then y else x`

Comment: `\unless\ifnum a<b` is the same as `\ifnum a>=b` also in the context of `\loop`.

Comment: I didn't use `a<b` because I think `\loop` ignores the false case.  Thanks @egreg for pointing out the `\unless` macro works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest `\loop` at the same level of grouping, see [Tex Nested Loops](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22877/4427)

For the problem of `>=` you can use

```
\loop\unless\ifnum \value{#1} < \value{#2}
```

You may also be interested in a fully expandable version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\euclid}{mm}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_abs:n { #1 } < \int_abs:n { #2 } }
   {
    \egreg_euclid:ff { \int_abs:n { #2 } } { \int_abs:n { #1 } }
   }
   {
    \egreg_euclid:ff { \int_abs:n { #1 } } { \int_abs:n { #2 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \egreg_euclid:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #2 = 0 }
    { #1 } % end
    { \egreg_euclid:nf { #2 } { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_euclid:nn { nf , ff }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\euclid{45}{27}

\euclid{45}{-27}

\euclid{27}{45}

\euclid{10}{0}

\euclid{0}{0}

\edef\temp{\euclid{2345}{356}}

\texttt{\meaning\temp}

\end{document}
```

The `\egreg_euclid:nn` macro calls itself recursively (using a variant in the subsequent calls in order to use “explicit” values for efficiency).

[image]

Also negative values are accepted and normalized at startup, so the gcd is always nonnegative.

Here's it accompanied by a `\fulleuclid` macro that shows the steps (only nonnegative numbers).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\euclid}{mm}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_abs:n { #1 } < \int_abs:n { #2 } }
   {
    \egreg_euclid:ff { \int_abs:n { #2 } } { \int_abs:n { #1 } }
   }
   {
    \egreg_euclid:ff { \int_abs:n { #1 } } { \int_abs:n { #2 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \egreg_euclid:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #2 = 0 }
    { #1 } % end
    { \egreg_euclid:nf { #2 } { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_euclid:nn { nf , ff }

\NewDocumentCommand{\fulleuclid}{mm}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_egreg_fulleuclid_swap_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l_egreg_fulleuclid_steps_seq
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 < #2 }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_egreg_fulleuclid_swap_tl { #1 &\leftrightarrow #2 \\ }
    \egreg_fulleuclid:nn { #2 } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \egreg_fulleuclid:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
  \begin{align}
  \tl_use:N \l_egreg_fulleuclid_swap_tl
  \seq_use:Nn \l_egreg_fulleuclid_steps_seq { \\ }
  \end{align}
 }

\tl_new:N \l_egreg_fulleuclid_swap_tl
\seq_new:N \l_egreg_fulleuclid_steps_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_fulleuclid:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #2 = 0 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_egreg_fulleuclid_steps_seq
     {
      #1 &= #2 \exp_not:N \cdot
      \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { #2 } +
      \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 }
     }
    \egreg_fulleuclid:nf { #2 } { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_fulleuclid:nn { nf }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\euclid{45}{27}

\euclid{45}{-27}

\euclid{27}{45}

\euclid{10}{0}

\euclid{0}{0}

\edef\temp{\euclid{2345}{356}}

\texttt{\meaning\temp}

\fulleuclid{356}{2345}

\end{document}
```

[image]